# How to click on RelativeLayout with UiAutomatorViewer

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-testing

I have

```
UiObject okButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("button1"));
okButton.click();
```

and it works perfectly I set `android:contentDescription="button1"` and everything works fine, the button is clicked and everything is okay.

but when I set `android:contentDescription="relativelayout1"` to relative layout then

```
UiObject rel1 = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("relativelayout1"));
rel1.click();
```

this code does produce `com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObjectNotFoundException`
but I am sure that the relative layout exists.

Does anybody else have made clicking to relative layout ?

Comment: Maybe a silly question but does the relativelayout have clickable enabled?

Comment: it is clickable and focusable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `.description("foo")` to find a UiObject by it's contentDescription